# Error: 'skipping incompatible ... when searching for -lRlapack' when compiling Rcpp package

Tags: c++, r, rcpp

I have a package that has stopped compiling on my windows laptop. I do not understand the error that I am getting however. got a new laptop and trying to reinstall my workflow. I have installed R, Rtools, Rstudio and when I try to install my package, the output is:

```
> devtools::install()
√  checking for file 'C:\Users\Chan\OneDrive - The Alan Turing Institute\freefor7\2019-07-02_Rcpp_exp_4_fusion\exp4FusionRCPP/DESCRIPTION' ...
-  preparing 'exp4FusionRCPP': (2.1s)
√  checking DESCRIPTION meta-information ... 
-  cleaning src
-  checking for LF line-endings in source and make files and shell scripts (588ms)
-  checking for empty or unneeded directories
-  building 'exp4FusionRCPP_0.0.0.9000.tar.gz'

Running "C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-36~1.3/bin/x64/Rcmd.exe" INSTALL \
  "C:\Users\Chan\AppData\Local\Temp\Rtmp0EgMPb/exp4FusionRCPP_0.0.0.9000.tar.gz" --install-tests 
* installing to library 'C:/Users/Chan/Documents/R/win-library/3.6'
* installing *source* package 'exp4FusionRCPP' ...
** using staged installation
** libs
-
*** arch - i386
C:/Rtools/mingw_64/bin/g++  -std=gnu++11 -I"C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-36~1.3/include" -DNDEBUG  -I"C:/Users/Chan/Documents/R/win-library/3.6/Rcpp/include" -I"C:/Users/Chan/Documents/R/win-library/3.6/layeredBB/include" -I"C:/Program Files/R/R-3.6.3/library/stats/include" -I"C:/Users/Chan/Documents/R/win-library/3.6/BH/include"        -O3 -march=native -mtune=native -c RcppExports.cpp -o RcppExports.o
C:/Rtools/mingw_64/bin/g++  -std=gnu++11 -I"C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-36~1.3/include" -DNDEBUG  -I"C:/Users/Chan/Documents/R/win-library/3.6/Rcpp/include" -I"C:/Users/Chan/Documents/R/win-library/3.6/layeredBB/include" -I"C:/Program Files/R/R-3.6.3/library/stats/include" -I"C:/Users/Chan/Documents/R/win-library/3.6/BH/include"        -O3 -march=native -mtune=native -c exact_algo_exp4.cpp -o exact_algo_exp4.o
C:/Rtools/mingw_64/bin/g++  -std=gnu++11 -I"C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-36~1.3/include" -DNDEBUG  -I"C:/Users/Chan/Documents/R/win-library/3.6/Rcpp/include" -I"C:/Users/Chan/Documents/R/win-library/3.6/layeredBB/include" -I"C:/Program Files/R/R-3.6.3/library/stats/include" -I"C:/Users/Chan/Documents/R/win-library/3.6/BH/include"        -O3 -march=native -mtune=native -c fusion_exp4.cpp -o fusion_exp4.o
C:/Rtools/mingw_64/bin/g++ -shared -s -static-libgcc -o exp4FusionRCPP.dll tmp.def RcppExports.o exact_algo_exp4.o fusion_exp4.o -LC:/PROGRA~1/R/R-36~1.3/bin/i386 -lRlapack -LC:/PROGRA~1/R/R-36~1.3/bin/i386 -lRblas -lgfortran -lm -lquadmath -LC:/PROGRA~1/R/R-36~1.3/bin/i386 -lR
:/Rtools/mingw_64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/4.9.3/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: skipping incompatible C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-36~1.3/bin/i386/Rlapack.dll when searching for -lRlapack
C:/Rtools/mingw_64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/4.9.3/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: skipping incompatible C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-36~1.3/bin/i386/Rlapack.dll when searching for -lRlapack
C:/Rtools/mingw_64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/4.9.3/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: skipping incompatible C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-36~1.3/bin/i386/Rlapack.dll when searching for -lRlapack
C:/Rtools/mingw_64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/4.9.3/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: skipping incompatible C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-36~1.3/bin/i386/Rlapack.dll when searching for -lRlapack
C:/Rtools/mingw_64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/4.9.3/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: skipping incompatible C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-36~1.3/bin/i386/Rlapack.dll when searching for -lRlapack
C:/Rtools/mingw_64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/4.9.3/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: skipping incompatible C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-36~1.3/bin/i386/Rlapack.dll when searching for -lRlapack
C:/Rtools/mingw_64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/4.9.3/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: cannot find -lRlapack
C:/Rtools/mingw_64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/4.9.3/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: skipping incompatible C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-36~1.3/bin/i386/Rblas.dll when searching for -lRblas
/ld.exe: skipping incompatible C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-36~1.3/bin/i386/Rblas.dll when searching for -lRblas
C:/Rtools/mingw_64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/4.9.3/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: skipping incompatible C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-36~1.3/bin/i386/Rblas.dll when searching for -lRblas
C:/Rtools/mingw_64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/4.9.3/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: skipping incompatible C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-36~1.3/bin/i386/Rblas.dll when searching for -lRblas
C:/Rtools/mingw_64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/4.9.3/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: skipping incompatible C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-36~1.3/bin/i386/Rblas.dll when searching for -lRblas
C:/Rtools/mingw_64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/4.9.3/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: skipping incompatible C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-36~1.3/bin/i386/Rblas.dll when searching for -lRblas
C:/Rtools/mingw_64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/4.9.3/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: cannot find -lRblas
C:/Rtools/mingw_64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/4.9.3/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: skipping incompatible C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-36~1.3/bin/i386/R.dll when searching for -lR
C:/Rtools/mingw_64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/4.9.3/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: skipping incompatible C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-36~1.3/bin/i386/R.dll when searching for -lR
C:/Rtools/mingw_64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/4.9.3/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: skipping incompatible C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-36~1.3/bin/i386/R.dll when searching for -lR
C:/Rtools/mingw_64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/4.9.3/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: skipping incompatible C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-36~1.3/bin/i386/R.dll when searching for -lR
C:/Rtools/mingw_64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/4.9.3/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: skipping incompatible C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-36~1.3/bin/i386/R.dll when searching for -lR
/x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: skipping incompatible C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-36~1.3/bin/i386/R.dll when searching for -lR
C:/Rtools/mingw_64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/4.9.3/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: cannot find -lR
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
no DLL was created
ERROR: compilation failed for package 'exp4FusionRCPP'
* removing 'C:/Users/Chan/Documents/R/win-library/3.6/exp4FusionRCPP'
* restoring previous 'C:/Users/Chan/Documents/R/win-library/3.6/exp4FusionRCPP'
Error in (function (command = NULL, args = character(), error_on_status = TRUE,  : 
  System command 'Rcmd.exe' failed, exit status: 1, stdout & stderr were printed
Type .Last.error.trace to see where the error occured
```

Comment: Most likely a local issue at your end, possibly your path or something you do to your setup.  A linker error `ld.exe: cannot find -lR` is grave.  I would try to make it simpler and simpler.  Try to compile the smallest possible package with no external dependencies (e.g. `digest` would fit this, or `gettz` which I updated yesterday and which is smaller).  Then try Rcpp itself.  Then try building against Rcpp.

Comment: @DirkEddelbuettel I can install `digest`, but unable to install `gettz`. I get a similar error: `cannot find -lR
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status`

Comment: That suggests trouble.  All respective packages work and build at CRAN as you can see on their pages, and the 'check' links they all have.

Comment: @DirkEddelbuettel I think I solved the problem that I had previously - I think my BINPREF environment variable wasn’t getting set correctly and I no longer get this error.

Comment: That type of non-standard setup would do it.